# Does static electric field feel force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I known that electric field can have momentum and energy.

Consider two particle at rest with same charge, the total force on one of the particle is zero,so the momentum of it is zero and not change, But at the same time if the electtric field  feel the reaction force, why not the electric filed obtain a momentum?

Consider the total momentum of the field and particle, the  external force is not zero, it should have a no zero momentum. But the momentum of static filed is zero, So what I missed?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, however imagine 2 charged particles at rest. Initially, there is net zero mechanical momentum and zero field momentum. After a time T, the particles are now moving towards eachother with some velocity. The particles both have equal in magnitude but opppsite momentum due to symmetry, and the EM field has some momentum density about all of space( which for this case due to symmetry sums to zero) The net sum of the momentum is the conserved quantity, not the individual momentum density at each point in the EM field, or the momentum of an individual particle

Comment: @jensenpaull OP says "same charge", so they will be moving away.

Comment: @Xian-Hui  static means "not moving". two same charge particles, even if they start at rest to each other, will repulse and the fields of the particles will follow the motions and will no longer be static.

Comment: Thanks for your  reply.

 1. I can understand the total momentum is conserved, but should it be locally conserved?

Comment: 2. Consier electric particle A and B，can I consider the electric field generate by A and particle B as a system ,  since the interaction is happened between them. A generate electric field , B feel the force. It seems like this system has no other force act on them. let's call this system as S.

Then I use another two forces FA and FB to force both A and B be rest, then the system S now   has a force  FB act on them, It shoud get a momentum ,but since the particle B now at rest and the field generate by A be static, the system  S doesn't has any momentum.

Comment: @Xian-Hui : can I get your email if you are interested to chat with me on electrostatics... I honestly won't share your email without your permission.